# eventcreate with multiline description

Tags: batch-file, eventcreate

I'd like to use eventcreate from a batch file to log the results of a file copy job (robocopy).  What I'd really like to do is use the output of the file copy job as the description of the event (/D of createevent).  The trouble is, there are multiple lines in the file copy output, and I've only been able to get one line into a local variable or a pipe command.

I've tried reading a local variable in from file, like

```
set /P myVar=<temp.txt
```

but it only gets the first line.

How can I write multiple lines to the description of an event from a batch file?

Comment: Beware ^L (control-L or ASCII 12) is a formfeed character, ^J (control-I or ASCII 10) is a linefeed character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the log and and change and CRLF to just LF (ctrl-l).

Here is an example:

```
EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /ID 1000 /l application /d "This is text^L this is line 2"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It's all on one line in the event log with the ^L printed out literally.

Comment: hmm I tested this out on windows 7 what OS are you running this on?  Did you type ctrl-l or ^L?

Comment: I think I copied and pasted.  Hitting Ctrl-l did the trick.  How would I get that into a batch file, though?

Comment: Using just native tools it's challenging.  The simplest way would be to use copy con to type the character into the file then use notepad to finish the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a [multi-line variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294599/do-batch-files-support-multiline-variables) by yourself, called `!LF!`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379619/explain-how-windows-batch-newline-variable-hack-works/6379861#6379861) post offers detailed explanation of how the newline hack/the `CMD` parser works.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

(set LF=^
%=--------DO NOT remove this line. Expands to nothing--------=%
)
set "lines=" reset LINES to 0
set "in=temp.txt"


call :readlines "%in%" lines

<"%in%" (FOR /L %%# in (1 1 %lines%) do (
    set "data="                                ::clear DATA
    set/p"data="                               ::read from IN
    set "fileContent=!fileContent!!data!!LF!"  ::manually construct multi-line variable
)) %= read file by lines via SET /P =%

EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /ID 1000 /l application /d "!fileContent!"
exit /b


:readlines FILE VAR
FOR /F %%L in ('
"findstr /N "^^" "%~1" %= do not skip empty lines =%"
') do set/a"%~2+=1" %= Get the # of lines =%
```

Screenshot:
[image]